# int + string unexpected output in c++

Tags: c++, computer-science, iostream, cout

I'm learning c++ nowadays and faced this code on CS106L course from stanford.
I don't get why it's output like that, i know that it's wrong to concatinate a string and int, but somehow i guess there's something about here that needs an explanation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string mostImportantOrders = "DO NOT LAUNCH THE MISSLES!";
void appendFour(int s) {
    cout << s + "4" << endl;
}

int main() {
    cout << "The total number of missiles is:" << endl;
    appendFour(44);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
The total number of missiles is:
NOT LAUNCH THE MISSLES!
```

Comment: pointer arithmetic. please see if you can find a suitable one of the duplicate questions.

Comment: can you explain it more? thanks @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Pointer arithmetic + undefined behaviour, to be precise.

Comment: "4" is a const char*.